# The support of IR v6 has been removed from the product

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, face-recognition, openvino

I am working on an Openvino project whenever I run the project it shows this error

> The support of IR v6 has been removed from the product. Please, convert the original model using the Model Optimizer which comes with this version of the OpenVINO to generate the supported IR version.

I think this happened in the model loading face-detection-retail-0005.xml

Comment: Based on the error, I imagine you should convert the model you're trying to use using the model optimizer.

Comment: how can I convert the model?

Comment: I googled for "openvino model optimizer convert model" and found this documentation: https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_Deep_Learning_Model_Optimizer_DevGuide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest Intermediate Representation (IR) model for [face-detection-retail-0005](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/omz_models_model_face_detection_retail_0005.html) (IR v11) from [Open Model Zoo](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/omz_tools_downloader.html) by running  the following command in [OpenVINO™ 2022.1 Development Tools](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/openvino_docs_install_guides_install_dev_tools.html):

```
omz_downloader --name face-detection-retail-0005
```

Refer to the [Model Downloader and other automation tools](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/omz_tools_downloader.html) for more information.

Comment: I am trying to download **senet50_ft** model but it gives the following error "No matching models: "senet50_ft". is senet50_ft is remove in the latest version?

Comment: The error you encountered was because senet50_ft model is not available in [Open Model Zoo](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/model_zoo.html). However, I did manage to find [se-resnet-50](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/omz_models_model_se_resnet_50.html) model which is available from [OpenVINO™ Toolkit Public Pre-Trained Models](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/omz_models_group_public.html).